# Execute npm start remotely from 2 locations

Tags: webpack, npm-start

Me and another person are working on the same files (php, js).

We run: `npm start` in order to compile our changes in our .js files, with webpack also.

We both connect to the main server throught putty.

But what happen if I'm already compiling NodeJS with `npm start` and he wants tu run `npm start` too from his terminal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it's possible to run simultaneously from 2 terminals a `npm star`, me and my co-worker were doing it without problems, and we both could see in the console the webpack messages.